# Can I run a kitchen sink drain 19' through a hollow stud wall with seven 90-degree turns?

Tags: plumbing, basement

I am adding a kitchen sink to a basement and want to run the sink drain through a hollow stud wall to reach the existing soil stack. My concern is it is 17' away and requires seven 90-degree elbows. Yes, seven. I know it's crazy, but this is what I have to work with. There is a pillar in the way which can't be moved, and I don't see any other options besides cutting a long trench in the concrete from the sink to the stack in the bathroom, which I really don't want to do. Three questions: 
1) Is this feasible?
2) Will it pass inspection?
3) Do I need a vent near the kitchen sink or will the stack in the bathroom serve as an adequate vent?

[image]

Comment: another option maybe build the whole wall out so you have a straight run.

Comment: If you have a 1-1/2 inch drain, with 1/4-inch per foot incline, wouldn't the maximum reach for a vent be 6 feet from the sink's trap?  Otherwise the vent connection would be lower than the trap weir, creating a siphon.

Answer (score 6):

Drilling holes in 17 feet of studs to accommodate a 1 1/2 inch drain line would not be recommended. The sheer number of studs impacted, including two corners, would definitely weaken the wall, especially if it is a exterior load bearing wall.

A second consideration with what is shown in your picture is that if it ever plugged it would be impossible to run a snake through such piping construction.

It is common to organize the house layout so that the plumbing routing is optimized and clustered into one particular area. This way you avoid much of what you are proposing. You may want to seriously consider just where you plan to put this kitchen sink and drains.

Comment: I agree a snake can make it through 3 -4 90s but any more there will be problems, also will there be enough slope on the pipe for it to drain 17' -
19' with only a foot of drop would be tough on a straight run , with all the 90' S no way.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider possibly pumping up overhead or break the floor.  Otherwise Michael is giving you the straight scoop.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you want to run the pipe though an outside stud wall next to your basement wall. This wall wouldn't normally be load bearing but for aesthetic purposes. (However, as Michael points out drilling large holes in all these studs could affect the strength of the wall.)

You would also need to add at least one two-way drain clean-out strategically placed near the center of the run and it would need to remain accessible. Also, you would need a vent stack or an Air Admittance Valve (AAV) at the sink.

I would consider a small ejector-style pump for the sink and then run the drain line overhead. I don't even know if they make a pump like this but it would be worth a look. They must make something for wet-bar sinks located away from the drain stack. Sump-style ejectors have to be vented all the way to the attic and require a hole in the basement floor. Almost more trouble than what you are planning.

Here are a couple pertinent sections to the International Building Code:

> **P3005.2.4 Change of direction.** Cleanouts shall be installed at each fitting with a change of direction more than 45 degrees (0.79 rad) in the building sewer, building drain and horizontal waste or soil lines. Where more than one change of direction occurs in a run of piping, only one cleanout shall be required in each 40 feet (12 192 mm) of developed length of the drainage piping.
>
> **P3005.2.5 Accessibility.** Cleanouts shall be accessible. Minimum clearance in front of cleanouts shall be 18 inches (457 mm) on 3-inch (76 mm) and larger pipes, and 12 inches (305 mm) on smaller pipes. Concealed cleanouts shall be provided with access of sufficient size to permit removal of the cleanout plug and rodding of the system. Cleanout plugs shall not be concealed by permanent finishing material.

Good luck with your project!

Comment: Sewage pumps and ejectors are often used in basement bathrooms, where the building discharge is above the fixture discharge, assuming local plumbing codes allow it (e.g., what if there is no electricity?).